# Why is my glass object purple in Viewport Shading mode?

Tags: modeling, shaders, glass

I created 3 framed artworks with a glass object. The images behind the glass object is not the problem, they are connected. It's the glass object in front of the 'artworks' that come up as purple/violet in Viewport Shading view.

[image]

These are my settings for the glass objects.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Is there another object behind/between the glass and the art image? Purple indicates missing references, like textures or shaders. Can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com/ ?